# Privacy issue on corporate device

Tags: privacy, mobile

On my corporate phone which has my Exchange account. Browsing incognito on my home WiFi. Can my employer find out what I am browsing on an incognito page? I am using am iPhone.

Comment: It all depends on what they have installed on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If the company has installed remote admin or remote monitoring software on the phone, then yes.

In general, if someone else gives you a phone, you cannot expect much control over the device.

But this is really a question that you need to discuss with your company's IT department. Most countries require that if they are monitoring you, then they need to inform you, or at least tell you if you ask.